# Put single quotes in a variable

Tags: node.js

I am trying to put quotes in a variable using node.js

In the following code:

```
req.on('end', function () {
      var postreq = qs.parse(body);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(postreq))    
    });
```

`console.log` prints `{"cmd":"sel_media","value":"5X7_photo_paper.png"}`

I want to put quotes around it like so: `'{"cmd":"sel_media","value":"5X7_photo_paper.p"}'`

I tried this way `"' +  JSON.stringify(postreq) + '"` it prints '`JSON.stringify(postreq)`'
I am not getting the exact values in single quote like I expected.

How can i get the values in singles quote like so: `{"cmd":"sel_media","value":"5X7_photo_paper.png"}`

Answer (score 3):

```
// Sample object.
var postreq = { cmd: "sel_media", value: "5X7_photo_paper.png" };

// Output JSON form enclosed in single quotes:
console.log("'" + JSON.stringify(postreq) + "'");
```